# running cassandra on mac

Tags: cassandra

i am trying to bin/cassandra -f and i get the following error. any help is appreciated.

xss =  -ea -javaagent:bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Xmn512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/service/CassandraDaemon
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon` means Cassandra has not been compiled correctly.  Run `ant` first.